# What is the easiest way to install kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, kernel, 20.04

I have the default Ubuntu 20.04 LTS kernel installed which is currently

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-7634-generic
```

I'd like however to install older kernel version of 5.3. I do see a package `linux-image-5.3.0-7648-generic` but when I try to install it Synaptic cannot find the actual package.

Do I miss some repo in /etc/apt ?

What would it be the easiest way to use 5.3 kernel and have it automagically upgraded whenever Canonical releases new 5.3.x version?

Comment: On my 19.10 it is already a 5.3.0-55 kernel... If you want recent kernels on LTS (beyond security updates) you can install the HWE (HardWare Enablement) kernel, it is updated for new hardware.

Comment: It is absolutely not catastrophic. I do select the right kernel with `grub` and it is possible to have as any kernel versions as you want. That's the way it has worked since 90s. My problem is that the package is is not available in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repos, as it used to be with 18, 16 and many older versions.

Comment: Having yet another kernel does not prevent you from automatic updates.  I used more than 10 kernel versions in Ubuntu 16 and 18. Why would it not work in 20?

Comment: Perhaps you can link another question or Q&A here that would discuss why having multiple kernels of multiple versions would not work in Ubuntu 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download and install the kernel binaries like so:

64-bit system:

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_all.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-modules-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo reboot
```

32-bit system:

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_all.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_i386.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-image-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_i386.deb

wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-modules-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo reboot
```

Hope that was helpful

Comment: Change `suso` to `sudo`. I'm surprised 32 bit is still around these days. Note however I doubt this automatically upgrades as OP requires.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is it possible to add some repo and use Synaptic / apt-get, so both tools do not get confused with out-of-the-scheme install?

Comment: I would not want to do that, the above works...

Comment: Hmm, I would deem contrary, but perhaps I am wrong. Would you please explain advantages of manual download and disadvantages of adding a repo?